# Amalgamated product of two measures.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Please do not get annoyed by the symbols below. The problem has a really simple statement.

$2^X$ denotes the set of functions from $X$ to $\{0, 1\}$ equipped with usual product topology. By $Fn(X, 2)$, we mean the set of all finite partial functions from $X$ to $\{0, 1\}$. For $p \in Fn(X, 2)$ and $Y \supseteq X$, we define $[p]_{Y} = \{y \in 2^Y : y \text{ extends } p \}$.

Suppose $A, B, C$ are pairwise disjoint countably infinite sets, $\mu_1$ is a regular Borel probability measure on $2^{A \cup B}$, $\mu_2$ is a regular Borel probability measure on $2^{A \cup C}$ and for every $p \in Fn(A, 2)$, $\mu_1([p]_{A \cup B}) = \mu_2([p]_{A \cup C})$. So the projections of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ to $2^A$ are identical.

I would like to construct an "amalgamated product" $\mu$ of $\mu_1, \mu_2$ in the following sense:

(0) $\mu$ is a regular Borel probability measure on $2^{A \cup B \cup C}$.

(1) For every $p \in Fn(A \cup B, 2)$, $\mu([p]_{A \cup B \cup C}) = \mu_1([p]_{A \cup B})$.

(2) For every $p \in Fn(A \cup C, 2)$, $\mu([p]_{A \cup B \cup C}) = \mu_2([p]_{A \cup C})$.

My guess is that for $p \in Fn(A \cup B \cup C)$, we can define $$\displaystyle \mu([p]_{A \cup B \cup C}) = \frac{\mu_1([p \upharpoonright (A \cup B)]_{A \cup B}) \mu_2([p \upharpoonright (A \cup C)]_{A \cup C})}{\mu_1([p \upharpoonright A]_{A \cup B})}$$

But I don't know how to show that this is finitely additive.